# how to access sign applet method from javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, applet, signed-applet

I want to access sign applet method from javascript; hence I create a html file like:

**html file:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function uploadFileApp(){   
    document.applets[0].FileCooserApp();
    document.uploadAppletFile.FileCooserApp();      
}
</script>
<html>
<h1>Applet Demo</h1>
<body>
<applet name="uploadAppletFile" code="TestApplet.class" archive="FileUpload.jar" width="400" height="300"></applet>
<input type="button" name="button" onclick="uploadFileApp();" value="Button"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**Applet Class:**

```
public class TestApplet extends JApplet{
    public TestApplet() {
    }   
    public String FileCooserApp(){
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        return path;
    }   
 }
```

as I shown in my html file I used both way to access applet method but when i click on button nothing action going to perform. and console shows nothing.

Comment: The access from Javascript to Java methods is not possible. Both languages use their own workingspace. (Java takes a seperate plugin)

Comment: @reporter no, its possible to access applet method from javascript, I was able to access that method but I don't know whats going wrong here that I am unable to access that method.

Comment: I looked up that in the Internet and apparently you're right.

Comment: *"console shows nothing."*  Make the console show something. -- Add `System.out.println("FileChooserApp invoked");` as the first line of the method.  Flush the class cache, reload the applet and check the string prints in the console.  Report back.

Comment: @AndrewThompson applet loads successfully at first time when program run but when am trying to call same method it gives error
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission user.dir read) at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source) at javax.swing.JFileChooser.getIcon(Unknown Source) 
so what should i do?

Comment: Calling that method from JS takes some extra work.  Calls to trusted methods need to be wrapped in an [`AccessController.doPrivileged(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html#method_summary) method.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I already written my code in AccessController.doPrivileged(...) but still same problem...

Comment: Did you flush the cache?  Put a `System.out.println("Test 1");` in the method to check you are seeing the new code.  Are you prompted to accept the digitally signed code?

Answer (score 0):

all in html

```
<object id="uploadAppletFile"
   classid="java:com/company/package/TestApplet.class"
   type="application/x-java-applet" 
   archive="FileUpload.jar"  
   height="0" width="0">
   <param name="code" value="com/company/package/TestApplet.class" /> 
   <param name="archive" value="FileUpload.jar" />
</object> 




<script type="text/javascript">
function uploadFileApp(){   
    uploadAppletFile.FileCooserApp();
}
</script>
```

Comment: @answered I write a code which you have given, when i run a program applet loads successfully and filechooser function gets call from init() but when i am trying to call same method from javascript its throwing error
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission user.dir read)
 at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JFileChooser.getIcon(Unknown Source)
 So what should i do?